# Photo organizer for Mac

Tags: osx, images, photography

I am looking for a Mac OS X application to organize my photos. The default iPhoto is lacking two major features which I really want/need:

- **automatically organize and group the photos by date**: I tried to manually create smart albums and filters for each year and month, but this becomes tedious work.
- **easily and thoroughly delete photos**: Delete doesn't work. Right-click and delete doesn't exist. Dragging into the Trash is not an option. `Command+Option+Delete` deletes the photo for now and it reappears at a later time.

Also, I'd like a free application, or inexpensive at the most. Other features are a bonus.

### EDIT

Picasa is not working the way I am interested in.

Also, the best example is the way Windows handles the photos in the pictures folder. The photos get sorted and grouped automatically.

### EDIT 2

I've also tried other applications, such as [Pixa](http://www.pixa-app.com/) and [Lyn](http://www.lynapp.com/), but none of them offer any sorting and grouping by date.

Answer (score 2):

I just saw this app some days ago: **[Pixave](http://www.littlehj.com/)**.
I did not try it, but it looks very clean and I think it's the app you are looking for. According to its documentation, it matches the requirements you've listed (also see the screenshot below to confirm):

- **automatically organize the photos by date:** The right-click menu offers you sorting by date (see the check-marked items in below screenshot)
- **easily and thoroughly delete photos:** Other than you've described for iPhoto, *Pixave* offers a "right-click and delete", as the screenshot shows

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

---

You can find more screenshots and detailed feature descriptions an the [Pixave website](http://www.littlehj.com/). If you want to get a better expression of the software, there's also a [Video Walk-Through at Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOKnBTLFSYM). You can also find an alternative description and ratings [at the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixave/id924891282?mt=12).

Comment: I've updated it once more, please cross-check. Hope that makes your downvotes go away now, as except for a "rating" none of us two can give (what makes this app recommendable?), it now should meet all criteria for a "good answer".

Comment: Unfortunately this application does not come with a free trial version, therefore I have not tried it yet since I do not want to pay for something I might not like. According the the developer, he'll be releasing a new version next week, which will have a free trial available on Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/). It's a free photo-editor by Google.

- Picasa can automatically organize photos by date but only **within each
  folder** (this may not be what you want).
- Pictures can be deleted from the file system from inside Picasa by pressing the `Delete` key. This shows a confirmation dialog the first time, in which you have the option to choose, "Don't ask again, always remove" for the future.

Other notes: When you permanently edit a picture, Picasa, by default, saves a copy of the original in a newly created 'Originals' folder as a subfolder in your picture's location.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Photos for Mac will sort by date in the Photos mode, but if you goto a moment, event or albums these are either sorted by title or manually sorted. No sorting available for now, but it is promised for the [next version](http://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/#photos) (see section on "Everything in its place" last sentence).

On the deletion issue, you do have the option in Photos to right click, and select delete. However they will usually be kept for upto 30 days, before being finally deleted. You can circumvent this by going to *File > Show recently deleted* and then click on the "Delete all" in the upper right corner.

In other words, I do believe that Photos does have what you are looking for, if not just now then in the next version!