# Photo management for Mac

Tags: osx, photography

I would like to organise my photos on a Mac.

I use photos both to record memories and as a hobby. So some of my photos are quick snapshots that I want to record in albums, and some are "hobby" photos, which are usually RAW files and there's often a lot of them as I tried to get the exact shot I wanted. I use the same camera for both of these. Additionally, I sometimes take photos at work, so as not to forget what was written on a whiteboard.

The features I'm looking for in particular are:

- I want to be able to cleanly separate my 'snapshot' photos from my 'hobby' ones and my 'work' ones, and manage them somewhat separately.
- I don't want a user interface that's based on thumbnails. Although I love photography my eye sight is pretty poor, so I want to do everything by flipping through full-sized views of the photos rather than squinting at tiny versions of them.
- I want to be able to select my "favorite" photos and look through those in chronological order, but to be able to easily access all the other photos that were taken around the same time. (I never delete photos unless they came out really badly, and I'd like to put the more average ones where they won't get in the way without making them hard to access.)
- I also want to be able to put photos in albums, separately from the favourites / time line feature above.
- For processing snapshots, basic exposure and colour correction features would be nice, but photo editing isn't my main concern.
- Free is preferable if the user interface is nice, but I'm willing to pay a reasonable cost.

I'm using the default "Photos" app at the moment, but it fails at the first two points<sup>1</sup>, and I'm not sure if any photo organising software supports the third one. There are a lot of other photo management programs available, but it's hard to get a good impression of what distinguishes them from one other.

<sup>1</sup><sub>For point 2, in Photos it's incredibly awkward to add a photo to an album without going back to the thumbnail view. Because of this, I find I'm just copying photos into folders instead, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a program to organise them.</sub>

Comment: There is [another question on the same topic](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3899/photo-organizer-for-mac?rq=1), but I hope it doesn't count as a duplicate because the poster is concerned with a different set of features. If it is considered a duplicate, my apologies.